# use spring mvc3 @ResponseBody had 415 Unsupported Media Type why?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

**spring xml:**

```
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="atom" value="application/atom+xml" />
            <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

 <mvc:annotation-driven />

 <context:annotation-config />

 <context:component-scan base-package="org.lxh"></context:component-scan>
```

and **code** is:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/2wt/test.do",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
Map<String, ? extends Object> create(
        @RequestBody WtStandartype wtStandartype) {
    System.out.println(wtStandartype.getId() + "--------");
    return Collections.singletonMap("id", wtStandartype.getId());

}
```

**javascript is:**

```
   jQuery.ajax({
                'type': 'POST',
                'url': '/2wt/test.do',//'WtStandardTypeList.do?addto=updb',
                'contentType': 'application/json',
                'data': JSON.stringify(jsonuserinfo),
                'dataType': 'json',
                'error':function(){
                    alert(222);
                },
                'success': function(){
                    alert(33333);
                }
            });
```

**web.xml is:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <web-app>
<display-name>jbpm</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:config/spring/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
    <description>Spring config file locations</description>
</context-param>


<listener>
    <listener-class>com.gzgi.framework.context.StartupListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.gzgi.framework.startup.ShutdownListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.gzgi.framework.context.UserOnlineListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>compressionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.gzgi.framework.web.filter.GZIPFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>compressionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>compressionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>compressionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.gzgi.framework.web.SpringDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.gzgi.framework.web.SpringDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>6</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rs/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<session-config>
    <session-timeout>3600</session-timeout>
</session-config>


</web-app>
```

I ajax submit the from but firefox view is   415 Unsupported Media Type

lib had jackson-mapper-asl-1.5.6.jar   jackson-core-asl-1.5.6.jar   spring version is 3.03

Why submit not success?

Comment: I add a web.xml but i not found this error where is

Comment: Did you finally find the solution to the problem?  I'm facing exactly the same issue.

Comment: Has anybody resolved this issue? This has made me pull my hair all day now.

Comment: @EdwardLau: It's not clear why you have two view resolvers in your context: `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` and another `InternalResourceViewResolver` (named `viewResolver`) – you need to remove it try again (it should be hidden behind `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`).

Answer (score 2):

Try putting an explicit `Accept` Header of : `application/json`.

The [mvc-showcase](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-showcase) sample spring application has a message converters example which reads json and xml to the screen with JQuery for Ajax request, you can try and use that example to model your code.

Comment: @BijuKunjummen: I think, that header should be called `Accept-type`.

Comment: could u help me on thisnhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102452/spring-mvc-415-unsupported-media-type/18103943?noredirect=1#comment26502825_18103943